# eclipse - Add author name for existing files

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a web project contains more than 100 classes. I need to add author name for all classes. 
I found the way to add author name for new file using Shift+Alt+j.

But how to do it for all other files ?

Comment: Do you really mean for all classes, including inner classes, or for all Java files? This should be possible via file search and replacing using a regular expression.

Comment: @howlger I meant Java files. Can you explain how to do it by regular expression?

Comment: _Search > File..._ with something like `\A[\s\S]*?(?=(public|private|protected)\s*+[@]?\b(class|interface|interface|enum)\b)` and _Replace..._